# Purpose of @NotNull.List

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

When I looked among the standard [constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html) in Bean Validation API (JSR-303), I found the `NotNull.List` annotation. Its description is:

> Defines several @NotNull annotations on the same element

This is valid syntax:

```java
@NotNull.List({@NotNull, @NotNull})
private Object myObject;
```

But it makes no sense. Either the object is null or it is not. When would you use this annotation?

There are several other similar annotations like `AssertFalse.List` and `AssertTrue.List`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can have multiple @NotNull annotations that are mutually exclusive based on the group attribute.

```
@NotNull.List({@NotNull(groups=Foo.class,message="Some message!"), 
               @NotNull(groups=bar.class, message="Some other message!"})
private Object myObject;
```

I do agree it's a little silly for this example since only the payload and message can be affected, but it's probably there to remain consistent with the other annotations.

See [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As to the @NotNull case, multiple @NotNull annotations might be needed
 for different validation groups as @dfb explained. But the same may be
 accomplished by listing those groups in the groups attribute.
This is well explained [here with test cases](http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/1735/)

> In the bean validation API javadoc, for every constraint annotation,
>   there's a corresponding .List annotation. For example, for @NotNull,
>   there's @NotNull.List, for which JavaDoc says:
>
> Defines several @NotNull annotations on the same element
>
> What would you accomplish with multiple @NotNull annotations that you
>   cannot accomplish with one @NotNull?