# Bean Validation with XML: Multiple of Same Constraint on a field

Tags: java, xml, validation

Previous to the introduction of `@Repeatable` in Java 8, multiple of the same annotation on a field was not allowed.  For XML Bean Validation, the way around this was to create a nested @List annotation inside of a Constraint annotation.  For example, as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610788/purpose-of-notnull-list), nested inside of `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`, you have:

```
@interface List {

  NotNull[] value();
}
```

When using annotations directly in the java code (as is usually done), you can have multiple `@NotNull` annotations defined thusly:

```
@NotNull.List({@NotNull(groups=Foo.class, message="myObject may not be null for Foo"), 
               @NotNull(groups=Bar.class, message="myObject may not be null for Bar"})
private Object myObject;
```

However, I am trying to configure the validation in an xml file instead of in my code (which is less commonly done).

My xml bean validation looks like this:

```
<field name="myObject">
  <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.NotNull">
    <message>myObject may not be null for Foo</message>
    <groups>
      <value>my.package.Foo</value>
    </groups>
  </constraint>
  <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.NotNull">
    <message>myObject may not be null for Bar</message>
    <groups>
      <value>my.package.Bar</value>
    </groups>
  </constraint>
</field>
```

This isn't working for me... the validation simply doesn't happen when I do this.

I've looked for clues in the xsd: http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping/validation-mapping-1.0.xsd, but I'm not seeing a way to incorporate `@NotNull.List`.

What is the right way to use multiple of the same constraint in xml?